# SQL Server group and count

Tags: sql-server, join, count, group-by

I have two tables:

```
table machines
-------------- 
machineID
FaNo
Barcode
RoutingCode
Name


table log
-------------
logID
lineBarcode
machineBarcode
```

So, I'm trying to select all the machines through `log` where `lineBarcode` is something specifed.

```
SELECT * FROM machines JOIN log ON log.machinebarcode = machines.barcode WHERE log.linebarcode = 100000000001
```

There are some records in `machines` which have same `routingCode` which means they are the same model.
How can I get there count separately?
I mean I need to get something like

```
Result
---------------------------------------
RoutingCode     Name          Count

B4            Machine1         10
C8            Machine21         7
D1            Machine12        43
```

So at all the query without group will have 50 records in return and the idea is to group them by routingCode and get their count from the query.
Is this possible and if is how? :)

Comment: Ammm it is in the last `code` section on the question :) I need to have the count of the records grouped by the routing code, but I don't have a clue how can I get COUNT() to be displayed on many rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT routingcode, name, count(1)
FROM machines 
LEFT OUTER JOIN log ON log.machinebarcode = machines.barcode
WHERE (log.linebarcode = 100000000001) OR (log.linebarcode is null)
GROUP BY routingcode, name
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Can you explain my why is count(1), I mean what is the 1 standing for?

Comment: you can do count(*), whatever, query optimizers should handle correctly doing this.  It's basically just telling it to count how many rows match that grouping.

Comment: Ahaa, thank you! Just another question: I tried to set the JOIN to LEFT, just because I wanna list all the machines groupped even if they do not exist in the matching `line` in the `log table`, but nothing happens, what am I missing? Shortly: I want it to select all the machines, but on those who have match in the `log.machinebarcode` I want to get the proper count, for the non-matched I guess it have to show zero?

Comment: the where clause will keep the left join from doing anything, unless you give it something like WHERE log.linebarcode = 100000000001 or log.linebarcode is null

Comment: Hmm is there a way to do this? I mean, I have to have the WHERE clause  for `linebarcode` otherwise the returned results are not usable for me :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RoutingCode, Name, COUNT(logID) AS 'Count'
FROM machine
JOIN log ON log.machinebarcode = machine.barcode
WHERE log.lineBarcode = 100000000001
GROUP BY RoutingCode, Name
```

This will give you the result you wanted.

Good luck*

Comment: Why would you use `like` for a `varchar` rather than `=`?